# Java : How to get Date rather than time?

Tags: java, date

Is it possible that i can get todays date , rather than time ??

This is my code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{   
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date today = calendar.getTime();

}
```

Why is todays date is shown as before date ??

```
public class Ravi {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Todays Date"+dateFormat.format(date));


        List currentObject = new ArrayList();

        currentObject.add("2012-09-27");

        Date ExpDate = dateFormat.parse((String) currentObject.get(0));

        System.out.println("ddd"+ExpDate);

        if (ExpDate.before(date)) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want todo with the Date object? Date is a thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

Comment: Today's date as a `Date` or a string?

Comment: I need to compare it with todays date so that currentdate.before(todaysdate) is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Date is always the full current time e.g. 2012.09.27 12:45:23

Whilst your new Formated date is 2012.09.27 00:00:00 therefor the output is correct.

If you want to get false you will need to set hours, minutes and seconds to 0.

Using Calendar:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Using Date:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comparing Dates with Calendar:

```
Calendar old = Calendar.getInstance();

old.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

old.before(now));
```

Note you may want to set Hours Minutes and Seconds to 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));
```

It will print  **2012-09-27**

Answer (score 1):

Getting today date in yyyy-MM-dd format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String output = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is todays date is shown as before date ??

when you do  `dateFormat.parse("2012-09-27");`
date what you will get it will be 00h00min00sec 2012-09-27
so when you compare it with `new Date();` you will get today date but couple hours(and minutes, and seconds) later, and that is why "2012-09-27" is before new Date()

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Date date=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
            String strDate=sd.format(date);
            String dateNow=strDate.substring(0,strDate.indexOf(" "));
            String timeNow=strDate.substring(strDate.indexOf(" ")+1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use two distinct SimpleDateFormats instead. One for only date, one for only time.

Comment: Correct, I thought probably this is what Preethi Jain was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{   
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date today = calendar.getTime();
sysout(dateFormat.format(today))
}
```